# The identification variable 'name' is not defined in the FROM clause

Tags: jpa, named-query

I am trying to run a named query in my bean but unfortunately it wont work. I get the following error.

`Problem compiling [SELECT d FROM IncentiveEntity d WHERE name = :name]. 
[38, 42] The identification variable 'name' is not defined in the FROM clause.`

Following is my code in the bean.

```
String s = "SELECT d FROM IncentiveEntity d WHERE d.name= :%s";
        s = String.format(s, "bla");
        IncentiveEntity a = (IncentiveEntity) em.createQuery(s,IncentiveEntity.class).getSingleResult();
```

I have tried it many other ways possible like removing `colon` in the query, but it wont work and give different errors. I have found many solutions online but nothing worked, I had to post it here following is the code for my entity class if it helps.

```
@Entity
public abstract class IncentiveEntity {


    @Id //Primary Key
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;



    private String init_name;


     @OneToMany(mappedBy="incfk", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
     private List<BeverageEntity> bvgfk;


     public List<BeverageEntity> getbvgfk() {

            if(this.bvgfk == null)
                return new ArrayList<BeverageEntity>();
            else
                return new ArrayList<BeverageEntity>(this.bvgfk);
        }
        /**
         * @param rooms the rooms to set
         */
        public void getbvgfk(List<BeverageEntity> or) {
            this.bvgfk = or;
        }


    public int getid() {
        return this.id;

    }

    public String getName(){
        return init_name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.init_name = name;
    }


}
```

Comment: try with `init_name= :name`

Comment: @pirho `init_name` has null value in the database. This entity is ab abstract class and name is coming from its execution. However, I tried your way and got following error. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument Usman not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution.`